# Register Dockerized microservice to Eureka server - Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, microservices, netflix-eureka

In my production environment I have an Eureka Server running inside a docker container.

I can register to it other basic microservices with this kind of Application.yml

**Application.yml**:

```
server:
  port: '8095'
spring:
  application:
    name: sap-listener
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://172.17.0.2:8761/eureka
```

I create a `DockerImage` with this Dockerfile:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY target/sap-listener-*.jar /sap-listener.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/sap-listener.jar" ]
EXPOSE 8095
```

and then I run it in production with this command:

```
docker run -d -p 8095:8095 --name sap myrepo/sap-listener1.0:latest
```

The service is successfully registered to the Eureka server.

I came across to some problems when I try to run a bigger microservice which have a docker-compose file.

I send directly this docker-compose file in production:

**Docker-compose**

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  docker-mysql:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
    ports:
      - "3007:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    container_name: php-my-admin-users
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
  ldap-app:
    image: myRepo/service1:latest
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306/db
    depends_on:
      - docker-mysql
```

And I run it with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d`

service1 application.yml have the same type of connection with Eureka server of the previous microservice.

service1 is correctly deployed but It can't register himself to the Eureka server, if I log out the container output I have this error:

> 2022-06-29 15:45:20.551  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://172.17.0.2:8761/eureka/}, exception=I/O error on GET request for "http://172.17.0.2:8761/eureka/apps/": Connect to 172.17.0.2:8761 [/172.17.0.2] failed: Connection timed out; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 172.17.0.2:8761 [/172.17.0.2] failed: Connection timed out stacktrace=org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://172.17.0.2:8761/eureka/apps/": Connect to 172.17.0.2:8761 [/172.17.0.2] failed: Connection timed out; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 172.17.0.2:8761 [/172.17.0.2] failed: Connection timed out

I read that someone directly insert the Eureka Server data as a service inside the `Docker-Compose.yml` file, but my Eureka Server is already deployed and is already listening to a specific port.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably happening because docker-compose automatically assign a network to the containers.

Try adding `network_mode: host` to your services in the compose file, like so:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  docker-mysql:
    network_mode: host
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
    ports:
      - "3007:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    network_mode: host
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    container_name: php-my-admin-users
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
  ldap-app:
    network_mode: host
    image: myRepo/service1:latest
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306/db
    depends_on:
      - docker-mysql
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

In this way I obtain this error: 

`CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: docker-mysql`

Comment: Try changing to `network_mode: bridge` or setting `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db` as the datasource url.

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest you get familiar with how [networking in Docker](https://docs.docker.com/network/) works and then have a look at [networking in Docker-Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

When you run `docker network ls` when your containers are deployed you will see that they are running on different networks, which isolates them. Inspect the networks using `docker network inspect <id>` and you'll see they have different subnets. So for the services to be able to communicate they need to be on the same network.

You can manually create a network and use it in both compose and the docker cli.